# Exception thrown from Finally clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I know that generally, we shouldn't expect a state in which exception is thrown from finally clause, however, I see cases in which that may happen.

What is your approach regarding it, would you enter another `try except` nesting to the `finally` clause?

This sounds somewhat weird....

Comment: Exceptions can be thrown from a `finally` block the same as from anywhere else. Whether it's appropriate or not depends on the situation and what you want to happen.

Comment: Butis it ok to enter another try except clause in finally? Or its could be a bad practice
(I've never seen this before)

Comment: Yes you can put a `try` block inside a `finally` block if it is appropriate to your situation.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example for your question, or is it basically about general opinion?

Comment: Yes I do logging inside the finally clause for final results of things ran on `try` clause, and that is because if exception is raising from the `try` section I will log it for sure.

Comment: Question is when I do the logging itself I don't launch any validation function to verify I have all keys in the dictionary passed for the logger, so I can end up thoratically with another exception raised , if the dictionary got messed, in this case I would at least print to log the traceback

Answer (score 1):

> I know that generally, we shouldn't expect a state in which exception is thrown from finally clause, however, I see cases in which that may happen.

It's not really common for there to be stuff in the `finally` clause, which could throw errors, but it's certainly allowed. I would advice you to think that is it really necessary for your use case (hard to say when your question is so general).

> would you enter another try except nesting to the finally clause?

Yes that is really the only way to handle it. It could for example be handled like this:

```
try:
    maybe_error()
except SpecificError:
    handle_error()
finally:
    try:
        risky_close_resource()
    except OtherError:
        handle_other_error()
    finally:
        close_everything_without_risks()
```